# How to sendback response attributes from Spring to Non Spring Java application on different server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cross-domain

I am sending a request from a Non-spring java application in X server to another application in X server which is a Spring application.(req 1)
I am also sending a similar kind of request from Y server Spring application to the X server Spring application.(req 2)

For both the requests, it hits the X server Spring application successfully. Now the next thing is, after all the processing is done in X server Spring controller,it send the request to Y server Spring controller (for both req1 and req2) for further processing. (req 3)

it is also being done successfully. Now the final part which i need your assistance.
When req 3 for both the applications(X server non Spring and Y server Spring) hit, Y server successfully runs the logics for the two different requests coming from X server controller in different methods successfully, but then when i need to send back the response from Y server to X server Non Spring application (setting attributes in request and then using request.sendredirect), it is failing. However, when we sending the response(in modelandview) for Y server spring application, it is getting received successfully.

i know the information i have provided is not sufficient, but i only need your guidance technically on how can i send back the response from Y server spring controller to a X server non-spring application. What are my options. I have attached a drawing to make you understand the situation better.

[image: diagram]

Comment: +1 nice explanation. Since you mentioned that `sending the response(in modelandview)` is success what else exactly is required ?